# How to perform the OneToMany Hibernate mapping when reverse reference is just an id attribute, not full reference

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, mapping

Let me be more specific, it was hard to describe this in the title.

I have a class called Bucket, which has a map to a series of Labels. The Bucket class has an id attribute. The class Label doesn't have a reference back to Bucket, instead it has a bucketId field which contains the id of the owning bucket. This was necessary to avoid circular references (Bucket to Label and back Label to Bucket) in order to allow the Bucket objects to be converted to JSON notation.

My Bucket class looks like this:

```
@Entity(name="Bucket")
@Table(name = "BUCKETS")
public class Bucket implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "BUCKET_ID")
    protected long id;

    /*
     * Map of labels indexed by the label name. I'm not sure this mapping is correct!
     */
    @ElementCollection
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @MapKeyColumn(name="LABEL_NAME")
    private Map<String, Label> labels = new HashMap<String, Label>();

    ...

}
```

and the Label class looks like this:

```
@Entity(name="Label")
@Table(name = "LABELS")
public class Label implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "LABEL_ID")
    protected long id;

    /*
     * How do I map this? It should point to the id of the Bucket instance that has
     * this label in its "labels" map
     */
    protected long bucketId;


    @Column(name = "LABEL_NAME", length=250, nullable=false)
    private String name;

    ...

}
```

If I could have a Bucket reference in the Label, I would map it as a @OneToMany and then in the Buckets class I would map as @ManyToOne(mappedBy="bucket"), but I don't have that reference, just the id pointing back.

**Does anyone knows how do I map this?**

Thank you!
Eduardo

Comment: A better solution would be to find a JSON library that lets you handle the circular paths gracefully instead of breaking your hibernate mappings.

Comment: You should not have a Bucket reference in your Label; you are setting yourself up for nasty bugs.  I'm not sure what circular reference you are talking about; it seems to me you are doing a standard one-to-many mapping.

Comment: The circular reference is Bucket to Label and Label to Bucket. This cannot be converted to JSON, which I have to, without excluding the inverse (Label to Bucket) reference from the serialization.

I will move forward with the Jackson which can reconstruct these bidirectional references on deserializations, but I'd still would like to know who to accomplish this mapping for curiosity sake. It might come handy in the future for me or someone else.

Comment: If you do the standard one-to-many mapping, you do not get any circularity.  There is no reference to Bucket within Label and no reference to Label within Bucket.  The standard one-to-many mapping is implemented with a join table.  As @Ryan Stewart mentioned, you might want to figure out how this is usually handled with JSON (maybe you also pass the join table as JSON?).

Comment: Bidirectional relationships between mapped entities are extremely common. Changing your Label class to only hold the bucketId instead of the bucket is a common reaction to this type of problem, but it's never the right one. In fact, it's not really worth knowing how to do it because it will only dig you into a deeper hole. Learn more about your marshaling library and how to handle this type of relationship. For example, using JAXB with Jackson behind it for JSON output, you can simply annotate one side of the relationship as @XmlTransient, and the problem goes away.

Comment: @toto yes it would be circular if I had a Bucket reference in the Label class (Bucket -> HashMap -> Label -> Bucket). In the posted code I didn't have that last Label -> Bucket reference to avoid the problem, but as @Ryan Stewart pointed out it's best to solve this in the JSON conversion side than messing the hibernate model for it. I solved by using Jackson which allows fields to be annotated and circular references to be reconstructed from a json expression at deserialization time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I am not able to comment below GeorgeG's answer, so I am responding to your second question here:

In order to set the bucketId in the Label after the Bucket has been created, you'll need to register an EventListener to do what you want to, for example (this is not necessarily working code).

```
    public class LabelPostInsertListener implements PostInsertListener {

        public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event)
                throws HibernateException {
            Bucket bucket = (Bucket)event.getEntity();
            for (Label l : bucket.getLabels().values()) {
                l.setBucketId(bucket.getId());
            }

        }
    }
```

Google Hibernate EventListeners for details on configuration and the like, there are many different types, though PostInsertListener should do be right for this situation.

Comment: Awesome, that should do it! Like I said I did it with Jackson library to avoid the circular reference, but I wanted to know how that would be done anyways for curiosity. That was the answer! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

```
@ElementCollection
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@MapKeyColumn(name="LABEL_NAME")
private Map<String, Label> labels = new HashMap<String, Label>();
```

First off the above mapping cannot be correct. Either use @ElementCollection OR @OneToMany, not both.

As far as the mapping of the buckedId field goes, i would just map it as a normal Long field in the Labels table. You could initialize the field with the correct bucketId, when you add a Label to a Bucket. Something like this (in the Bucket class):

```
public void addLabel(Label label) {
    labels.put(label.getName(), label);
    label.setBucketId(this.getId());
}
```

However make sure, the bucketId field in the Labels class cannot be set to an incorrect value. You could for example reduce the visibility of the setter for the bucketId field.

Comment: Actually there is a problem with this approach. I just realized that the Bucket id will only be assigned after it has been made persistent. I cannot set it to labels when they are added because this happens before the Buckets class is persisted (and at that time there is no id assigned yet).